# Jena Riot Exception when loading valid turtle file

Tags: jena

I have a turtle file located [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noorbakerally/ISWC2017Demo/master/ParisGeo.ttl). I have validated it using [this tool](http://ttl.summerofcode.be/) (http://ttl.summerofcode.be/) and it says that the turtle file is valid. However when loading it using Jena with `RDFDataMgr.loadModel("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noorbakerally/ISWC2017Demo/master/ParisGeo.ttl");` I am getting the following error,

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 1, col: 1 ] Expected BNode or IRI: Got: [DIRECTIVE:prefix]
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.fatal(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:136)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.raiseException(LangEngine.java:148)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.exceptionDirect(LangEngine.java:143)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangEngine.exception(LangEngine.java:137)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTuple.checkIRIOrBNode(LangNTuple.java:89)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.parseOne(LangNTriples.java:74)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangNTriples.runParser(LangNTriples.java:53)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangBase.parse(LangBase.java:41)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserRegistry$ReaderRIOTLang.read(RDFParserRegistry.java:194)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.read(RDFParser.java:293)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parseNotUri(RDFParser.java:283)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParser.parse(RDFParser.java:233)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFParserBuilder.parse(RDFParserBuilder.java:405)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.process(RDFDataMgr.java:862)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.parse(RDFDataMgr.java:676)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:222)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:103)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.read(RDFDataMgr.java:94)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr.loadModel(RDFDataMgr.java:336)
    at fr.emse.opensensingcity.main.main(main.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: you can try and specify the language `RDFDataMgr.loadModel("ParisGeo.ttl", Lang.TTL);`

Comment: nopes, I tried but it doesn't solve the problem, i think TTL is already the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That link returns an HTTP header with "text/plain". The MIME type declaration is used, not the file extension.

You force the syntax by building a configured parer with `RDFParser`.

http://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-input.html#example-3-using-rdfparser

Or open a stream to the URL in Java and use `RDFDataMgr`

From the command line, `riot --syntax TTL ...`